# How to share ONLY several fields of the contacts

Tags: google-contacts, google-workspace-for-business, sharing, crm

I already know how to share google contacts with my team.
But I need to share only SEVERAL fields with each people.
Imagine I wish to share all contacts but not all the information, but only phone number to the customer team,  only account fields to account team, and only social media fields to the marketing team.

How can I CHOOSE the fields to share in Google Contacts?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately **sharing only selected fields** of Google Contacts is not supported at this time. However, you are free to request such functionality:

[image]